# How would I got about creating a new column that shows if the "Project Column" is the latest?

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable

Here is what the I have.

Select Product ID, Revision
FROM Project_Table

| ProjectID | Revision |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | 1 |
| 122 | 2 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 124 | 1 |

And the excel file looks something like the table above. I want to create a new column called latest_rev. Where 122 with revision 2 would say True and 122 revision 1 would say false. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

would go with `max() over(partition by )`

```
select ProjectID, Revision
    , case when Revision = max(Revision) over(partition by ProjectID) then 'True'
        else 'False' end as latest_rev
from Project_Table;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cTviPAJ6jfxdBxJV1h48KK/1),
[Function Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

Edited
to add new column with `update`

```
alter table Project_Table add latest_rev varchar(5) NULL;

with cte as (
  select ProjectID, Revision
  , case when Revision = max(Revision) over(partition by ProjectID) then 'True'
        else 'False' end as latest_rev
  from Project_Table
) 
update Project_Table, cte set Project_Table.latest_rev = cte.latest_rev
where Project_Table.ProjectID = cte.ProjectID
  and Project_Table.Revision  = cte.Revision;
```

new [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cTviPAJ6jfxdBxJV1h48KK/3), documentation on [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! If you don't mind me asking, how would I go about adding the table latest_rev to the existing table rather than a query?

Comment: Sure!, @johnnnieyy. Edited to update the table.